# Linked list: Not working as expected

Tags: java, linked-list

I created a singly linked list , it giving below error . not sure what is wrong, ant suggestion

Error/ OP - List is javaTest.LinkedListcreation@1540e19d

I am not sure what this value in Output is meant for .

Process finished with exit code 0

```
public  class LinkedList{

public static  void main (String[] a){
    LinkedListcreation L1 = new LinkedListcreation();
    L1.addNodeAtEnd("1");
    System.out.print("List is " + L1);
}

}

class LinkedListcreation {

int listcount;
node head;

LinkedListcreation() {
    head = new node(0);
    listcount=0;
}


node Temp;

void addNodeAtEnd(Object d){
    node Current = head;
    Temp = new node(d);
    while (Current.getNext()!= null){
        Current = Current.getNext();
    }

    Current.setNext(Temp);

    listcount++;
}

}


class node {

Object data;
node next;

node(Object d) {
    next = null;
    this.data=d;
}

node(Object d, node nextNode) {
    next = nextNode;
    this.data=d;
}

   public Object getdata(){
   return data;
   }


public void setdata(int d){
    data = d;
}

public node getNext(){
    return next;
}

public void setNext (node nextValue){
    next = nextValue;
}
}
```

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: Remember to stick to Java's naming-conventions. It makes things easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everybody said, you have to override `toString()`. Here you have the right implementation:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[");
    sb.append(head.data.toString());

    node n;
    while(n = head.getNext() != null)
        sb.append(", " + n.data.toString());

    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is all right, but in order to print useful information about an object (your list in this example), you need to override the `toString` method in your `LinkedListcreation` class.

For example:

```
public String toString() {
    return "List with " + this.listcount + " nodes.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to print the list object rather than the element which you have added and more over what you see is not error. check about toString() method in java to understand the output which you see.

Modify your main() as below to see the element you added.

```
 public static  void main (String[] a){
   LinkedListcreation L1 = new LinkedListcreation();
  L1.addNodeAtEnd("1");
   System.out.print("List is " + L1.head.next.data);
```

}

**output** : List is 1

Comment: And if the list has more than one element?

Comment: obviously,you have to write one more method to fetch the element at particular index :-)

refer : http://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/

Comment: @KDP ....i m little confused .........how in the below example they are able to print linked list just by using the linedlist name .... http://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/

Comment: refer toString() method, when you try to print a object it will implicitly call toString() method. to see meaningful data you should override toString() method.  refer http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-tostring-method

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have any error. If you want to print the nodes in your list you just have to add another function in you LinkedListcreation class which will iterate over your list and print each node's data. Add this block in your LinkedListcreation class.

```
public void printList(){
node current = head.next;
while(current!=null){
    System.out.println("node's data is: "+ current.getdata());
    current = current.getNext();
}
```

}

Also in your main function call the above mentioned function using your list's object L1.

```
L1.printList();
```

Answer (score -1):

The code has compiler errors.  Try corrected code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class LinkedList
    {

        static void Main(String[] a){
           LinkedListcreation L1 = new LinkedListcreation();
           L1.addNodeAtEnd("1");
           Console.WriteLine("List is " + L1);
        }

    }

    public class LinkedListcreation
    {

        int listcount;
        node head;

        public LinkedListcreation()
        {
            head = new node(0);
            listcount = 0;
        }


        node Temp;

        public void addNodeAtEnd(Object d)
        {
            node Current = head;
            Temp = new node(d);
            while (Current.getNext() != null)
            {
                Current = Current.getNext();
            }

            Current.setNext(Temp);

            listcount++;
        }

    }


    public class node
    {

        Object data;
        node next;

        public node(Object d)
        {
            next = null;
            this.data = d;
        }

        node(Object d, node nextNode)
        {
            next = nextNode;
            this.data = d;
        }

        public Object getdata()
        {
            return data;
        }


        public void setdata(int d)
        {
            data = d;
        }

        public node getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(node nextValue)
        {
            next = nextValue;
        }
    }

}
​
```

Comment: Umm... Which language is _this?_ For sure no Java.